# MVVM pattern where hold current view details

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm, model, viewmodel

Where should I hold data like current combobox selected item, current calendar selected dates, current datagrid selected row, current calendar selection mode etc... ?

Better is View Model or Model ?

I think every data should be in Model but in the other hand when situation needs logic part or starts more actions after changes it will be stupid to put logic to Model. Model also shouldn't (in my opinion) calls View Model methods so it is a little problem for me.

What's yours opinion?

Edit: Only using in WPF is intresting for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those things should go into the view-model because they are related to the user interactions with the user interface, or perhaps they are are more related to the state of the user interface.

If you look at it from another perspective you will find that is not related to the model in any way especially that you have found your self calling view-model methods from the model.